# How to map the key ";" in Neovim

Tags: vim, neovim

using the following syntax, I can press "fd" instead of escape in Vim/Neovim:

```
:imap fd <Esc>
```

I would like to do the same for the key ";", assigning it to the same function as when I press "$" (going to the end of the line). However, this does not work:

```
:imap ; <$>
```

What am I doing wrong ? Thank you in advance.

Comment: `$` doesn't go to the end of line, it inserts a `$` in insert mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You can only use the [`:help key-notation`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/intro.txt.html#key-notation) for special keys (like `<Esc>`). A `$` is just `$`.
- [You should use `:noremap`](http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/05.html); it makes the mapping immune to remapping and recursion.
- Do you really want to make it cumbersome to enter a literal `;`?! In insert mode, only *unprintable* left-hand sides (e.g. mappings with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> or <kbd>Alt</kbd>) make sense.
- To have the mapping in other modes, see [`:help :map-modes`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/map.txt.html#%3Amap-modes). (But why would you want an alias for the short `$` command in normal mode?)
- In *insert mode*, `$` is not a valid command. You could use `<End>` instead:

```
:inoremap ; <End>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can change config like this:

```
"<esc> means change to normal mode, then "$" goto the end of line, "a" re-enter insert mode
imap ; <esc>$a
```

If you just want goto the end of file without re-enter insert-mode, remove the tailing "a" letter.

Comment: Couldn't that just be `<esc>A`?

Comment: This solution works as I want but only if I'm on `insert` mode. Is it possible to have the same behavior in all modes ?

Comment: @Nakrule Then just use map instead of imap.

Comment: @Nakrule I just changed my answer. "$" is the command for the end of line, "E" is just command for the end of word. Sorry for that.